# Confusion in 'a Little' and 'Little'

Tags: adjectives

In my grammar book,
**A little** is defined as positive and **little** is defined as negative.

For eg:
**A little** common sense can bring you success.(positive)

then why do we say : 
**A little** knowledge is a dangerous thing.

```
and how is the use of just 'little' wrong here?
```

Comment: What's the point of defining either of these as positive or negative?  I'd ignore the grammar book and look at examples.  "Cute little puppies" is not negative.  A small amount of something can be a good thing--or not.  "Only a little water remained in my canteen."

Comment: but doesn't cute little mean small puppies here?

Comment: Yes.  So "little" means small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proverb "A little knowledge is a dangerous thing" is meant to subvert expectations. (Also, there are some problems with what your grammar book said.)

"Little knowledge" would mean "not much knowledge" or "almost no knowledge". It's obvious that this would be a bad thing. For example, if you said "You have little knowledge of the situation", it would most likely be interpreted as an insult meaning "You know almost nothing". But "little" can express a positive meaning when paired with a negative word: "I experienced little unhappiness during my time there". (Actually, I wouldn't recommend getting into the habit of using "little" in this way, because it sounds a bit archaic to me. But I hope you now understand what it means.)

"A little knowledge" isn't necessarily positive, but it doesn't imply insignificance in the same way that "little knowledge" does. "You have a little knowledge of the situation" isn't necessarily insulting, although it could be condescending if the speaker is aware that the person being addressed actually has a lot of knowledge. "A little knowledge" can mean, in effect, "some knowledge".

The proverb "A little knowledge is a dangerous thing" is meant to emphasize that, although people might think that "any knowledge is better than none", that is not actually the case. The proverb isn't "Little knowledge is a dangerous thing" because that doesn't express that idea as effectively  – it would be prone to being misinterpreted as meaning "It is dangerous to know little" (which is obvious, rather than counterintuitive, and so generally goes without saying) or even as meaning "Out of all the knowledge that exists, only a small amount is dangerous". Also, the version with "Little" instead of "A little" sounds awkward.

Comment: The meaning of the proverb makes it a lot clearer.But do you think the usage of little is correct grammatically even if it sounds awkward?And Thanks a ton for the detailed answer!

Comment: "Little knowledge is a dangerous thing" is not necessarily ungrammatical, but I tried to explain in the last paragraph why it is not a good way of expressing the idea of this proverb.

Comment: It's not a proverb, but a variant of a quotation from Alexander Pope "A little learning is a dangerous thing" See http://www.thisdayinquotes.com/2010/05/little-learning-is-dangerous-thing.html

Comment: @KateBunting: Thanks for the additional information! I think it's possible to say it has become a proverb--according to that link, "It became a proverbial saying"

Answer (score 0):

The contrast between ‘little’ and ‘a little’ can be augmented simply by translating the two into another language. I will use Esperanto for that purpose there, but you could equally use, say, French or German.
Anyway, in Esperanto ‘little’ is ‘malmulte da’, whereas ‘a little’ is ‘kelke da’.
Once you are up to speed on these two expressions, you will be able to decipher, and appreciate, the proverb.

Comment: I am staggered to learn from Wikipedia that between 1,000 and 2,000 sets of parents, worldwide, taught their children Esperanto _as a first language_ .

Comment: @Nigel J: Here’s my page of Esperanto links: http://www.public-domain-materials.com/folder-esperanto.html

Comment: Multan dankon. Tre interesa.